# Collisions between CharacterController and BoxCollider dont happen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to detect collision between the characterController and an empty boxCollider in an Unity project. Ive tryed to use OnTrigger stay, enter, exit but all of this didnt work, but in unity i see collisions.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GolVQ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St7tV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9zzt.png)

```
if (swipeUp && helloEnded)
        {
            Reset();
            p1 = transform.position + cc.center;
            if (Physics.SphereCast(p1, cc.height / 2, -transform.up, out checkDistUnder, 0.085f))
            {
                jumpDone = true;
                currentDistanceHit = checkDistUnder.distance;
                animator.SetTrigger("Up");
                jumpDone = false;
                Debug.Log(jumpDone);
            }
            else
                jumpDone = false;
        }
```

Comment: There are a lot of reasons it may not work. Most of which described well in the documentation.   Show some simple code. Explain what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

To detect collision either (or both) object must have rigidbody attached to it.

Objects must be able to interact with each other according to the collision matrix, but since both are on default layer I guess that's not the case.

If still stuck, then check if you are using correct method (OnTriggerEnter for triggers, OnColliderEnter for colliders).

Documentation reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: I added SphereCast to character, and now collision between him and ground happens, but also possible to do double jump by doing two fast swipes. Code is above.

Comment: That's probably material for another question. My wild guess is that your variable jumpDone doesn't do all that much since you set it back and forth during one frame, hence allowing for double jump. Haven't you managed to do that with colliders? I advise you look into it, since it's very important aspect of creating games in unity.